# can you remove items off the ground without entering the minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

my friend has spawned in 9000 water buckets right next to me and the game crashed, so i was wondering if it was possible to remove items from the ground not in the server

Answer (score 3):

Type `kill @e[type=minecraft:item]` from the console to remove all dropped items in the world.

Comment: Don't dropped items use the `minecraft:item` entity ID?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I did not have the game at hand to confirm it. I have edited it.